# Omni-Channel : Taking ownership of cases manually doesn't remove the PSR record and get routed to other agent

Tags: servicecloud, omnichannel, omni-supervisor

We have set up Omni-channel with the status-based capacity model. In certain cases, the manager/supervisor needs to manually assign the case to the agent (ex. case sitting too long in the queue and needing immediate attention).

When the manager or agent takes ownership of the case manually from the Omni-enabled queue, the PSR record (a record which is shown in Omni-supervisor ) doesn't get removed, instead, the same case is routed to the next available agent. This is creating a lot of confusion and Salesforce support is not of much help.

Question: Is this how status based capacity model works? doesn't allow manual ownership of the case to be taken ?

If yes, what are the possible workarounds ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain the lifecycle of the case? Is it routed to the next available agent immediately? I have the same issue when a case is reassigned to a user outside of Omni, closed, and then reopened by a customer. The answer is in the 'PSR and AgentWork Lifecycle':  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_psr_lifecycle.htm
Case will never be removed from Omni queue as either PSR OR AgentWork record exists. It is not possible to delete it as both records are immune to changes.
I am considering cloning the case if it should be routed outside of the Omni queue

Answer (score 1):

You can create a flow to delete the PSR.  When the owner is changed (someone else has taken ownership), it triggers the flow to get the PSR (WorkItemID = Record ID) and deletes it.  This will remove it from further routing.

Comment: It is not possible to delete PSRs

Comment: @MatthewMetros PSR can be deleted. We always delete old PSR and recreate new in prod to handle omnichannel performance issue

Comment: @KaonZ we get an error as soon as we delete the PSR with the error message that this record is not able to be deleted